# Questions about implementing the Uncheck feature when clicking radio button again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

The vacation type is composed of a radio button to select the type of vacation.
If you are not going on vacation, click the radio button of the vacation type to uncheck the checked items.

I'm trying to implement a function that is unchecked when I click the radio button again using react-hook-form, but it's not as easy as I thought, so I'm posting.

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const {
    register,
    formState: { errors },
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    setValue,
    watch,
  } = useForm();

  const [test1, setTest1] = useState(false);
  const [test2, setTest2] = useState(false);

  const handler1 = () => {
    if (test1 === true) {
      setValue("TEST", "");
      setTest2(false);
    }
    setTest1(!test1);
  };

  const handler2 = () => {
    if (test2 === true) {
      setValue("TEST", "");
      setTest2(false);
    }
    setTest2(!test2);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        className="input formInput"
        {...register("TEST_NAME", {
          validate: (value, formValues) => {
            return (
              value !== "" ||
              formValues.TEST === null ||
              "please name"
            );
          },
        })}
      />
      <span> type1</span>
      <input
        type="radio"
        value={1}
        onClick={(e) => {
          handler1();
        }}
        checked={test1}
        {...register("TEST", {
          validate: (value, formValues, e) => {
            //console.log(e.target.value);
            return (
              value !== null ||
              formValues.TEST_NAME === "" ||
              "selected vacation"
            );
          },
        })}
      />
      <span> type2</span>
      <input
        type="radio"
        value={0.5}
        onClick={() => {
          handler2();
        }}
        checked={test2}
        {...register("TEST", {
          validate: (value, formValues) => {
            return (
              value !== null ||
              formValues.TEST_NAME === "" ||
              "selected vacation."
            );
          },
        })}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the case of the above code, it can be canceled by selecting the radio button and clicking it again.

The problem is that if you click the type1 radio button and then click the type2 radio button, you must click the type1 button again, uncheck it, and click the type2 button to check it.

If you click the type2 radio button directly from the type1 radio button, it does not click.

And using useState, re-landing occurs every click, eliminating the advantages of react-hook-form.

If any of my friends have implemented the Uncheck feature when I click the radio button again using react-hook-form, can you help me?

I tried to implement it as a check box and go in a way that does not make duplicate choices on the check box, but it was not easy, so I chose the radio button.

[enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/5jncqk?migrateFrom=dy9vyn&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltw7e9iz0006356lmbsf0wry%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltw7e9ix0002356ldy2r5r3g%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltw7e9ix0004356l4a2pdlai%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltw7e9iy0005356laaf2dwkq%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cltw7e9ix0002356ldy2r5r3g%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltw7e9ix0002356ldy2r5r3g%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522cltw7e9iy0005356laaf2dwkq%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltw7e9iy0005356laaf2dwkq%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltw7enia00eg356lnakg5vac%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522Development%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltw7enia00eg356lnakg5vac%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522cltw7e9ix0004356l4a2pdlai%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltw7e9ix0004356l4a2pdlai%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltw7eitf008b356lyblsozzx%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltw7e9ix0003356lhjoouys5%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522cltw7eayf001bdbf8dc13bxzb%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522Development%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltw7eitf008b356lyblsozzx%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Comment: If you are still having issues please reproduce it in a react playground so we can take a look

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Modified the code above. After installing the react-hook-form in codesandbox, I can copy and paste the code and test it right away

I posted a link in the article

Comment: Hi, thanks for updating your post with a reproducible link. It seems you were attempting to reinvent a radio button's internal mechanics which is not advisable. Secondly you are mixing native implementation with react-hook-form's approach (pick one). Take a look at this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/boring-hooks-dy9vyn-forked-j4zdx7) and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: I checked the sandbox you uploaded. I solved it by referring to the sandbox you uploaded. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem. I will create an official answer